# What is $\ker (4,-4)$

Tags: vectors

I found this equation in a textbook:

$$\ker (4,-4)=\langle(1,1)\rangle$$

It's the first time I see this operator and couldn't find a description of what's happening here. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is the set of values that are mapped to the zero element, so in this case $\operatorname{ker}(4,-4)=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:(x,y)\cdot(4,-4)=0\}$, these elements satisfy $4x-4y=0$, which holds if $x=y$ i.e. the set $\{(x,x):x\in\Bbb R\}=\langle(1,1)\rangle$.

Comment: Ok, so e.g. $\ker(2,1)=\langle (x,-2x) \rangle$?

Comment: it would be $\langle(1,-2)\rangle$

Comment: Ok, I arleady thought so. One last thing: What does the $\langle (\, ,\, )\rangle$ mean?

Comment: @kaos $\langle (a,b) \rangle$ denotes the linear span (over $\Bbb{R}$, in this case) of the vector $(a,b)$, i.e. the set of all the vectors of the form $(\lambda a, \lambda b)$ with $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Even more generally $\langle\rangle$ defines a set generated by a specific element.